# Node6 error on object.assign with rest parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using object.assign and rest parameters to help transform and organize my data before displaying in the UI. I used to run this below chunk on the client/browser and it ran great, but moving server-side it now fails.

```
Object.assign(objectA, ...objectB);
```

Both are objects, and objectB is something null

I'm running Node v 6.11.5 and the error message being reported on this line is

> TypeError: undefined is not iterable

Looking around it seems Node6 doesn't support these operators well, how can I either

- make this work in Node6
- re-write this line in a more supported form?

Comment: You can use a transpiler like babel to convert the code to an older version before you run the code.
https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

Comment: I updated the offending line to `Object.assign(objectA, ...(couldBeUndefined || []));` per Jordan's suggestion below which works great. I still don't know why it worked in the browser but fails in Node, but at least I have a solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error doesn't have anything to do with Node 6<sup>†</sup>. You'll get the same error in any version of Node from version 5 to 12 (and presumably all future versions).

The error message is pretty clear:

> TypeError: undefined is not iterable

You can only use the spread operator on iterable objects (like arrays), but `objectB` is `undefined`, which is not iterable.

If you're not expecting `objectB` to be `undefined`, then you have a bug somewhere before this code. If you're expecting `objectB` to be `undefined` sometimes then you could fix it in a few ways. If `objectB` is a function argument, you could give it a default value:

```
function myFunction(objectA, moreObjects = []) {
  // ...
  Object.assign(objectA, ...moreObjects);
}
```

...or you could just make sure it's not `undefined` on the line where you use it:

```js
const objectA = { foo: 1 };
let couldBeUndefined;

const result = Object.assign(objectA, ...(couldBeUndefined || []));

console.log(result);
```

---

<sup>†</sup>You should, however, unequivocally stop using such an old version of Node. Node 6 is [no longer maintained](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) (i.e. no security updates). The version [recommended for most users](https://nodejs.org/) is 10.16.

Comment: Thanks for all the info... but that's not the case. I'm running the exact same code on the exact same data in the browser and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger to determine the actual value of `objectB` at the call site? I can assure you that using the spread operator on `undefined` will give you an error in Node 10 and Node 12, and that it will do the same in a modern browser (I just tried all three), so there's definitely something else going on here.

Comment: okay thank you I will investigate further then and see.. I would like this to be the problem then it's an easy fix :)

Comment: So I confirmed that the rest operator works as I suggested even with undefined, before the offending line I added `if (!objectB) log('objectB is null');` and indeed it reported as so a buncha of times, and everything in the code ran perfectly.. any other ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting to work. Using the spread operator on `undefined` will indeed produce the error you're describing on Node 6.11.5 for the reasons I described. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEdRb.png) If you're certain that `objectB` is an iterable object, then the error is coming from somewhere else and you'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58083279/edit) to show us more of your actual code and the backtrace for the error message. And, again, `console.log` is not a substitute for stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: I am using the identical line of code on identical data on the browser and it produces no error. I am trying to solve via alternate means now, but it always bugs me when things aren't consistent and I'm trying to figure out why/how to make it work

Comment: adding your suggestion of `(couldBeUndefined || [])` totally works great and I'm using it now as my solution; however... it still bugs me that it works in the browser but not in node with identical everything else

Comment: Believe me, it bugs me too! Thanks for accepting my answer. If you figure out the cause, please let us know in case it helpful for others.

Answer (score -1):

Use an [Object.assign polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).

Then, assuming ObjectB is an array:

```
Object.assign.apply(Object, [objectA].concat(objectB || []));
```

Comment: `Object.assign` is support in all versions of Node since 4.0. Using the linked polyfill in Node 6 would be a no-op.